# What is the intuition behind calculating the error of sum of squares and square of a shifted sum using moving averages?

Tags: geometry, average

Given $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, then the following holds:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{d}v_i^2
-\frac{
\Big(
(\sum_{i=1}^dv_i)-\beta
\Big)^2
}{d}    
&=
\beta(2w_1-\beta)
+
\sum_{i=2}^d
\frac{i-1}{i}
\Big(
w_i - 
\frac{
(\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}w_j)-\beta
}{i-1}
\Big)^2
\end{aligned}
$$
for $\mathbf{w}=\pi(\mathbf{v})$ where $\pi(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary permutation of components in $\mathbf{v}$. For example, $\mathbf{v}=[1, -5, 6]^{\top}$ then $\mathbf{w}$ can be $[-5, 1, 6]^{\top}$,  $[6, -5, 1]^{\top}$, etc.

**Question**

What is the intuition behind calculating the error of sum of squares and square of a shifted sum?

**My observation**

The formula to me looks like calculating the error on the left hand side using moving averages on the right hand side as if it is a time series. The larger the $d$ the smaller the effect of $\beta$ would be in the long run. No matter what components you start with, eventually you would get the same answer.

**Note**

Please sure your thoughts as a comment until we get enough information that can be posted as the solution.